# How to print a nested map-map-vector

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I am having issues loading and printing my map-map-vector data structure. I think it's on the printing side, since I am not 100% sure how to use iterators.

I created and loaded the data into the structure to store my data here:
(I created inner_test and myvector because it looked like I needed them for the iterators. I'm not sure how the iterators know that inner_test and myvector are part of test though.)

```
map<int, map<string, vector<string>>> test;
map<string, vector<string>> inner_test;
vector<string> myvector;

ifstream thisfile;
const char *file1 = argv[1];
thisfile.open(file1);
string filler;

while( thisfile >> filler ){
    string sortedFiller = filler;
    sort(sortedFiller.begin(), sortedFiller.end());
    test[filler.length()][sortedFiller].push_back(filler);
}
thisfile.close();
```

I tried to print it with this, but I don't think I quite understand what I'm doing here.

```
map<int, map<string, vector<string>>>::iterator itr1;
map<string, vector<string>>::iterator itr2;
vector<string>::iterator itr3;

for(itr1 = test.begin(); itr1 != test.end(); itr1++){
    cout << itr1->first;
    for(itr2 = inner_test.begin(); itr2 != inner_test.end(); itr2++){
        cout << itr2->first;
        for(itr3 = myVector.begin(); itr3 != myVector.end(); itr3++){
            cout << *itr3;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: You could simplify a lot with `multimap<pair<int, string>, string>`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I didn't know about multimap. If the key is a pair, do I have to supply the pair? Or can I return all data that corresponds to an input key of '3'?

Comment: Good question.  You need to search using a pair.  However, you can call `mm.lower_bound(make_pair(3, string()))` to get the first value with 3, and `mm.lower_bound(make_pair(4, string()))` to get one past the last.  That is basically what you need as far as I can see.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thanks. I'll take a look and see which way to go. I'm looking for efficiency and maybe multimap if the right choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `inner_test`, and `my_vector` variables are empty containers, and are unrelated to the actual `std::map`, you want to print, in any way. This is one of the examples how can you print multidimensional container:

```
    // auto type automatically defines itself as a return type of test.begin ()
for(auto itr1 = test.begin(); itr1 != test.end(); itr1++)
    {
    cout << itr1->first << ' '; // Add space to separate entries on the same line
    // itr1->second represents map<string, vector<string>> stored in test.
    for(auto itr2 = itr1->second.begin (); itr2 != itr1->second.end (); itr2++)
        {
        cout << itr2->first << ' ';
        // itr2->second represents vector<string> stored in map<string, vector<string>> which is stored in test.
        for(auto itr3 = itr2->second.begin(); itr3 != itr2->second.end(); itr3++)
            {
            cout << *itr3 << ' ';
            }
        }
    cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Thank worked perfectly. So the inner_test and myvector variables are only created so that the iterator has a shell of the same structure type to use to build the iterator?

Comment: @user1362058 No, you don't need those variables, at all, as I stated in the answer with the statement _Your `inner_test`, and `my_vector` variables are empty containers, and are **unrelated** to the actual `std::map`_

Comment: OK. I completely misunderstood what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Use `auto` to deduce type of iterators automatically like `for(auto itr1 = container.begin(); ...`.

Then, before second loop, add `const auto& inner_test = itr1->second;` and iterate over your nested map like you did.

Similarly, before third loop, add `const auto& myVector = itr2->second;`.

What is going on here.

In C++ it's possible to overload `*` and `->` operators. Iterators do that.

When you iterate over `std::map`, iterator points `std::pair` of references to key and value. Pair has `first` and `second` fields which are, in this case, references to key and value respectively.

Also, use `.cbegin()` and `.cend()` -- const iterators -- if you don't want to alter data in map.